# How is the Visvarupa of Lord Shiva different from the Visvarupa of Lord Krishna?

Tags: shiva, krishna, bhagavad-gita, gita

Lord Shiva showed Visvarupa to Lord Rama as per the Shiva-Gita. Lord Krishna showed the Visva-rupa to Arjuna as per the Bhagavad-Gita.

Are these two 'Visva-rupa' Forms identical or different? If different, what are the differences?

If there are many differences, just mentioning upto five will be enough.

Answer (score 2):

It was mentioned that Sri Krishna/Shiva showed Viswa Rupa.  However, even Rig Veda says, Indra took Viswarupa.

Rig veda [III.38.4](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv03038.htm) is dedicated to Indra.  There it was mentioned that Indra took **OMNIFORM - विश्वरूप**.

> आतिष्ठन्तं परि विश्वे अभूषञ्छ्रियो वसानश्चरति सवरोचिः | महत तद वर्ष्णो
>   असुरस्य नामा **विश्वरूपो** अम्र्तानि तस्थौ ||
>
> Even as he mounted up they all adorned him: self-luminous he travels
>   clothed in splendour. That is the Bull's, the Asura's mighty figure:
>   he, **omniform**, hath reached the eternal waters.

So what will be description of Viswarupa?  Arjuna, who was the witness of Viswarupa, got terrified, and prayed to withdraw the Viswarupa.

Hence, it is next to impossible to describe Viswarupa, as [Sri Krishna himself stated](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35043/3869), while disclosing Viswarupa to Arjuna, to view ***whatever he wanted to see - द्रष्टुमिच्छसि".***, but did not say he was showing his REAL Viswarupa.

Whatever may be the form in which one prays to the Almighty God, be it Shiva/Krishna or something else, the **OMNIFORM - विश्वरूप**, will be ONE AND THE SAME.

Comment: " it is next to impossible to describe Viswarupa," this is not true. A description is given in the bg. "but did not say he was showing his REAL Viswarupa." Why would Krishna show him a false one?

Comment: Please read my answer carefully at the following link.(https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35043/3869).    This link was already provided in the answer. @Wikash_

Answer (score 0):

Both the visvarupra of Shiva and Krishna are identical, the omniform can be better understood by understanding the following verses of Vedas first.

> Sarvam Khalvidam Brahman' '**All this is indeed Brahman**'
>   - Chandogya Upanishad 3.14
>
> In the beginning this was Self alone, in the shape of a person
>   (puruṣa). He looking around saw nothing but his Self (Atman). He first
>   said, "This is I", therefore he became I by name. —Brihadaranyaka
>   Upanishad 1.4.1

**All the avatars are of same Purusha/Brahman/Paramatma/Supersoul who is omnipresent as souls of all beings**. People are just using their bodies and earth for a period but are ignorant of God around them because of their temporary egos of temporary body, born with the power of avidya Maya, they have not created their bodies nor the world around them. Who is the creator and cause of everything? That alone is depicted in Visvarupas shown by various avatars like Shiva, Krishna etc., taken by one formless Brahman since worship of formless is difficult than worship of God with a form. Infact the ever changing inert material universe is created alone to understand the formless eternal Supersoul Purusha. Sanatana Dharma is a Henotheist religion where the hymns of the Rigveda, the oldest scripture of Hinduism, mention many deities, but praises them successively as the "one ultimate, supreme God", alternatively as "one supreme Goddess", thereby asserting that the essence of the deities was unitary (ekam), and the deities were nothing but pluralistic manifestations of the same concept of the divine (God).

> They call him Indra, Mitra, Varuna, Agni, and he is heavenly-winged
>   Garutman. To what is One, sages give many a title.
>
> — Rigveda 1.164.46
>
> BG 5.18: The truly learned, with the eyes of divine knowledge, see
>   with equal vision a Brahmin, a cow, an elephant, a dog, and a
>   dog-eater.

Brahman/Atman was also explained by Yagyavalkya, one of the wisest sage in the courtyard of Janaka after defeating other learned scholars of Vedas. [Brihadaranyaka Upanishads](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc118359.html)

> 3.8.9. **Under the mighty rule of this Immutable, O Gārgī, the sun and moon are held in their positions; under the mighty rule of this Immutable,
>   O Gārgī, heaven and earth maintain their positions; under the mighty
>   rule of this Immutable**, O Gārgī, moments, Muhūrtas,[2] days and
>   nights, fortnights, months, seasons and years are held in their
>   respective places; under the mighty rule of this Immutable, O Gārgī,
>   some rivers flow eastward from the White Mountains, others flowing
>   westward continue in that direction, and still others keep to their
>   respective courses; under the mighty rule of this Immutable, O Gārgī,
>   men praise those that give, the gods depend on the sacrificer, and the
>   Manes on independent offerings (Darvīhoma)
>
> 3.8.10. He, O Gārgī, who in this world, without knowing this Immutable, offers oblations in the fire, performs sacrifices and undergoes
>   austerities even for many thousand years, finds all such acts but
>   perishable; he, O Gārgī, who departs from this world without knowing
>   this Immutable, is miserable. But he, O Gārgī, who departs from this
>   world after knowing this Immutable, is a knower of Brahman.
>
> 3.8.11. **This Immutable, O Gārgī, is never seen but is the Witness; It is never heard, but is the Hearer; It is never thought, but is the
>   Thinker; It is never known, but is the Knower. There is no other
>   witness but This, no other hearer but This, no other thinker but This,
>   no other knower but This. By this Immutable, O Gārgī, is the
>   (unmanifested) ether pervaded.**

Comment: I think this is a bad answer. You did not show that the visvarupra are identical at all. You merely showed that everything is brahman. Pls show that these forms are identical.

Comment: @Wikash_ Just because you cant understand it, that doesnot mean its bad. If you cant understand Einstein's theory of relativity or Ramanujan's equations, does that mean Einstein and Ramanujan are a failed scientist, mathematician. Purify your mind first to understand God as spirit is purest of all untainted by any material corruption. A first class student cant understand 10th class text books.

Comment: And if everything is Brahman so automatically, all forms are of Brahman. Its logical unless you are a skeptic.

Comment: If all forms are brahman then they should have the same strength, knowledge etc. Yet only three gods are all knowing: the trideva. So we cab acknowledge that there are differences in the manifestations.

Comment: "Just because you cant understand it, that doesnot mean its bad" I did understand it and he does not answer the question. There very large differemces between sifferent manifestations of god.

Comment: @Wikash_ everything is in God and is god already, but not for an inferior bound soul like of animal, insects, Tamsik men who are slave of senses and his ego, an enlightened Gyani even he dies in a brothel or graveyard is absorbed back in Brahman, because Brahman has become everything even prostitutes and corpses. Trinity itself is not supreme but manifestation of feminine 3 formed Prakriti. Even masculine form is unreal, Man is formless in reality Purusha/Brahman. Differences exist because your mind is impure because of lust, greed and anger. God is in you but you are not in God.

Comment: read this. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32175/is-everything-in-the-universe-conscious-according-to-hinduism/32212#32212 First renounce things, practice continence, vegetarianism and give up greed of wealth, lust, lying and hatred for others than alone you can understand God who is Spirit and truth. I am not here to argue with kids like you. You are a child in the field of spirituality and focussed on cramming scriptures like parrot.Spirituality is to be pursued practically and learnt under a True Guru but not learnt by cramming up 2-3 hymns over internet.

Comment: Like I said earlier only the trideva are omniscient they know everything and are each 1/3 of the Brahman himself. The idea is that there are very large differences between different manifestations of the Brahman. To say that the Vishnu is Shiva is a misconception as they are different.

Comment: "everything is in God and is god already" this idea is wrong. The brahman created everything and manifests in different ways hence the large differences. "You are a child in the field of spirituality and focussed on cramming scriptures like parrot." The brahman communicates to us via the scriptures. To refute the scriptures is to refute the Brahman.

Comment: @Wikash_ I am not here to argue with Abrahmics like you who live among adharmi Mlecchas, who dont even know their own Bible nor follow Jesus teachings properly. Have you seen Shiva or Vishnu? You are just another joker and slave of copulation and body pleasures,  I have seen many like you. Death will give you your answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99521/discussion-between-manu-kumar-and-wikash).

Comment: Nice answer.  Up voted. @ManuKumar