# Why Brahma is called Lotus born?

Tags: advaita, brahma, lotus

Why Bramha who is self-born i.e. manifested on its own as per Yoga Vasistha, also called Lotus born as per Yoga Vasistha? What is the meaning of lotus here? Is it simple flower or something else very deep?

> असत्य एव कचति स्वप्ने खोड्डयनं यथा ।
>  इत्यनुत्पन्न एवासौ स्वयंभूः
>   स्वयमुत्थितः ॥ ३८ ॥
>
> 3.13.38 The unproduced and self-born Brahma, that has risen of himself (and represents the mind), is as unreal as the soaring of a man in the
>   sky in his dream.
>
> कृत्वा पद्मजसंकल्पं रूपं पश्यति पद्मजम् ।
>  ततो जगत्कल्पयति
>   सप्रजापतिपूर्वकम् ॥ ८ ॥
>
> 4.40.8 Taking the conception of the lotus-born, it finds itself in its conceived form of the lotus (Brahma), and then it thinks of creation
>   in the form of Prajapati or lord of creatures.

Comment: Lotus is metaphor used for Aatma, just like peepal is metaphor of body used in Geeta. Just like a lotus flower floats in dirt, so does a Brahmgyani remains untouched by Tamas or darkness all around because of Vidya/wisdom.

Comment: If you could cite the source for "lotus stands for Atman" and write an answer, I will mark it as accepted. @ManuKumar

Comment: Its pretty obvious, puranas were written for people of Kaliyuga who could only believe in what is seen just like Tamsik animals, there is no actual lotus in sky nor are multiple hands of God, these are all metaphors. Puranas are support of Vedas/Vedanta which deal with only one entity Atman, who is glorified using several names and metaphors of Maya or manifested reality.

Comment: But why only Brahma is called lotus born and not Vishnu or Shiv or Surya? While Shiva, Vishnu and Bramha all 3 are called swambhu (self born) at different texts.

Comment: Again these are different names of same Atman based on working just like a man is husband , son, father at same time, have you read about Vishvaroop of Krishna shown during Geeta to Arjuna https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36610/16530. Shiva, Brahma, Vishnu are all names of Brahman, infinite is not finite. One who see differences is not worthy of Moksha for how could a jiva with differences in mind be ever free of hatred and ever find peace. If Shiva, Vishnu or Brahma were different from inside, they would have been battling for lordship of universe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the history of Brahma's birth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36499/what-is-the-history-of-brahmas-birth)

Comment: So initially, Brahma created himself and emerged from a Golden egg, earning him the name Hiranyagarbha. However at the beginning of the Padma Kalpa, Vishnu and Brahma entered each other’s bodies. When Brahma entered inside Vishnu, Vishnu closed all openings and this Brahma came outside through a lotus growing from Hari’s navel. Hope this answers your question: [History of Brahma’s birth](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36499/what-is-the-history-of-brahmas-birth/36500#36500)

Answer (score 1):

> Why Brahma is called Lotus born?

Because he is [born from the navel of Narayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38253/which-is-the-earliest-scripture-to-depict-brahma-as-the-navel-lotus-born-offspri) on a lotus.

Comment: But YV says He is self born and hence not born out of someone else.

Comment: @Lokesh Yes, the question is basically "How do we reconcile such apparently contradictory verses?" Different schools of Hinduism have different methods of reconciliation. According to Sri Vaishnavism, when a devata is described as "self born", the name of that devata is being used as a name of the supreme Brahman. So it is saying the supreme Brahman is self born.

Answer (score 0):

For the unreal lotus born BHAHMA in the above mentioned shloka of yoga vashishta,the reason for calling him lotus born might also be unreal. Why did Pandavas die at the age of 5? Because Ravana killed them with the help of his 5th real brother!!! Sorry, but this reasoning (to me) is probably more profound than the answer the questioner would be expecting( if at all he is real)